# While installing Xvid codecs for VLC, I've ended up with broken packages.

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

In trying to install Xvid codec for VLC on my Ubuntu 16.04, I somehow ended up messing my package system, such that I cannot even install software upgrades - neither through the `Software Updater`, nor through `apt-get upgrade`

```
$ apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxvidcore4 : Breaks: libxvidcore4:i386 (!= 3:1.3.2-dmo1) but 2:1.3.4-1 is installed
 libxvidcore4:i386 : Breaks: libxvidcore4 (!= 2:1.3.4-1) but 3:1.3.2-dmo1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

The two lines appear to suggest a cyclic dependency. How to remove these packages and get back to my previous working state?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
sudo apt-get remove libxvidcore4
```

It worked for me.